# Full text index doesn't work at single word?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I have a full text index on many columns of the `customer` table, one of which columns is `fname`.

The following query:

```
select * from customer where fname like 'In%' and code='1409584557891'
```

returns me the line needed, this customer has an fname of 'In' .But if I add this to the end:

```
and contains((customer.fname) , N'"In*"')
```

an empty result-set is retuned. **Why?**

Also: there is another column named lname. If I add the equivelant `contains` command with the column and its value altered, it works!

Comment: There is a good chance "In" is a noise word.  I also believe that if you do a fulltextsearch for something too short like the letter 'a' it is simply considered a noise word.  See if 'a' gives you anything. 
 https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1491/sql-server-full-text-search-noise-words-and-thesaurus-configurations/

Comment: well, "i" gives nothing. I consider your comment an answer.

Comment: cool, I'll post a nice little write up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good chance "In" is a noise word. I also believe that if you do a fulltextsearch for something too short like the letter 'a' it is simply considered a noise word. See if 'a' or 'I' gives you anything.

Here is a link that can provide information on changing the noise words around if that is the case.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1491/sql-server-full-text-search-noise-words-and-thesaurus-configurations/

You may also be able to simply turn off noise or 'stop' words:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/135062/sql-server-no-search-results-caused-by-noise-words